# How can i add footer at the bottom of the page wkhtmltopdf

Tags: php, html, css, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I am using wkhtmltopdf to genereate reports now i have encounterd with a situation where i have to show footer at the bottom of the page i have tried to solve this with css it works on simple page but not on my wkhtmltopdf generated page
here is my HTML code

```
<footer id="footer">
    <p>Hello World</p>
</footer>
```

And my css is this

```
#footer {
    position:fixed;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

I have also tried this code given on wkhtmltopdf page

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
    var vars = {};
    var x = document.location.search.substring(1).split('&');
    for (var i in x) {
        var z = x[i].split('=', 2);
        [z[0]] = unescape(z[1]);
    }

    if current page number == last page number
        if (vars['page'] == vars['topage']) {
            document.querySelectorAll('#footer')[0].textContent = 'extra text  here';
        }
    };
</script>
```

Note I am not using cmd command I am using CodeIgniter. Is their any option like

```
$this->wkhtmltopdf->setOptions(array(
              'orientation' => 'landscape'
                ));
```

Comment: Did you try position: absolute instead?

Comment: yes i have tried it it is working on simple page but not in wkhtmltopdf page

Answer (score 5):

When adding your page you can pass in a footer through the page options.

```
$footer = $this->load->view('footer', $data, true);

$page_options = [
    'footer-html' => "".str_replace("\n", ' ', $footer).""
];

$pdf   = new Pdf($pdf_options);
$pdf->addPage($view, $page_options); // page invoice
```

You can also use `header-html` as well for headers. This will apply the footer to each page you add with that option.

Comment: You should mark this answer and close issue you've opened https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/2238